# Dealing data imbalance without sampling techniques

Tags: machine-learning, classification, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am working on a binary classification with 977 rows (77:23) with label 1 being the minority class. I tried Random forest and it seems to work well. with a recall of 60% for minority class. But I would like to increase further.

Currently based on my research and discussion in the forum, am not interested in using any oversampling techniques. So, I am trying the below

a) class_weight, scale_pos_weight

b) F1-score as the metric

c) optimizing decision threshold (and not default 0.5)

Is there any other options that I have to handle class imbalance?

Can you please help me on how can I improve the data balance? unfortunately, we cannot collect more data.

Comment: You should always optimize the decision threshold for the problem where the model is being applied to. The benefits/costs of TP, FP, TN, FN should be optimized regardless of any class imbalance.

Comment: If you want perfect recall, that’s easy: just classify everything in the group that you want to recall. If this does not suit your needs (as I suspect it does not), please say why, as that discussion will be informative. // Please stop tagging all of your posts with neural network tags when you’re explicitly asking about other models and making no mention of neural networks.

Comment: Since it's costly for our business to miss to incorrectly classify a `1` as `0`, we would like to make sure that our model does better for `class 1` when compared to `class 0`. that's the reason am trying to maximize recall (for `class 1`). I use scoring metric as `recall` and model takes care of optimizing the metric for `class 1` because metrics like recall, precision with ML models are designed for `class 1`.

Comment: My comment yesterday told you how to achieve perfect recall.